# Flutter: Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/package_info)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I recently updated to Flutter v2 and wanted to start my Application in Chrome. I tried everything to fix the bug but nothing helps.

The whole Exception:

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/package_info)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:59662/dart_sdk.js:5355:11)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:59662/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:962:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:59662/dart_sdk.js:39215:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:59662/dart_sdk.js:39072:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:59662/dart_sdk.js:34058:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:59662/dart_sdk.js:34618:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:59662/dart_sdk.js:34656:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:59662/dart_sdk.js:34498:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:59662/dart_sdk.js:34521:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:59662/dart_sdk.js:39359:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:59662/dart_sdk.js:39365:13)
    at http://localhost:59662/dart_sdk.js:34872:9
```

It works perfectly fine on my IOS Emulator.

Answer (score 3):

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
  setState(() {
    // Here you can write your code for open new view
  });
});
```

Just Add Some Delay , and inside setState() do your Provider or Async Work Your Problem Will be Solved

Comment: should i add this code everywhere i open a new view?

Comment: For this I need to check your code

Comment: I post my code as answer because it is too long.

Comment: This answer would be improved by an explanation of why it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I added it as you said before opening a View.

```
new ListTile(
                            title: new Text("Favoriten"),
                            trailing: new Icon(Icons.favorite,
                                color: accentColor, size: 18),
                            onTap: () {

                              Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
                                setState(() {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) => Favourite(
                                          unfilteredCars, carProvider, this)));
                                });
                              });

                            }),
```

Comment: Is this a solution to the problem?  If not, please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The "Post Answer" button should be used only for complete answers to the question.